# Asp.net MVC API lock a function based on method parameters

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, locking

I have a helper function which deserializes an XML file, and generates c# objects from it.

After that, the objects are added into server memory. The only way of adding something in the server's memory is only through this function.

```
public class DeserializeXmlHelper
{
    public void DeserializeXml(Guid xml_Id, decimal version)
    {
        // heavy process here which takes about 3 seconds
    }
}
```

This function is being called by different clients using an API method (made in Asp.net MVC API).

When calling the API, can i prevent the execution of the function if somebody else already called the same function with the same parameters?

Something like this, but i don't know if it is a good way of doing it.

```
public class DeserializeXmlHelper
{
    private static readonly ConcurrentDictionary<string, object> _processes = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, object>();

    public void DeserializeXml(Guid xml_Id, decimal version)
    {
        string processKey = string.Format("{0}_v{1}", xml_Id, version.ToString("#0.0"));
        object processLocker = null;
        if (_processes.TryGetValue(processKey, out processLocker) == false)
        {
            processLocker = new object();
            _processes.TryAdd(processKey, processLocker);
        }

        lock (processLocker)
        {
            // heavy process here which takes about 3 seconds

            _processes.TryRemove(processKey);
        }
    }
}
```

**EDITED - New version**

Tim Roger's answer is working successfully.

However, if i want to return only when the initial call has finished, can i do something like this? (I am using ConcurrentDictionary because i don't know how to add locks, but the idea should be the same)

```
public class DeserializeXmlHelper
{
    private static readonly ConcurrentDictionary<string, string> _processes = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, string>();
    public void DeserializeXml(Guid xml_Id, decimal version)
    {
        string _processKey = string.Format("{0}_v{1}", xml_Id, version.ToString("#0.0"));
        string _processValue = null;
        if (_processes.TryGetValue(_processKey, out _processValue) == true)
        {
            // function already called with the same parameters
            do
            {
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100);
            }
            while(_processes.TryGetValue(_processKey, out _processValue) == true)

            return;
        }

        try
        {
            _processes.TryAdd(_processKey, _processValue);

            var begin = "begin process";

            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(10000);

            var end = "ending process";
        }
        finally
        {
            _processes.TryRemove(_processKey, out _processValue);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If the parameters are the same, is the result the same?

Comment: Yes, for the same parameters the same results

Comment: Could you just use a cache?  Look into the cache for the objects first so that you don't do the expensive generation every time?  You could potentially cache the entire result from the Web API call.

Comment: This function is called when the objects are not in cache anymore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your original solution was not far off but you seemed to always be running the process regardless of the current state.

Even though you have used a concurrent dictionary, you also need a lock to lock the entire dictionary while you are updating its state, since the thread could be interrupted between `TryGetValue` and `Add`.

```
private static readonly ConcurrentDictionary<string, object> _processes = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, object>();
private static readonly object _dictionaryLock = new object();

public void DeserializeXml(Guid xml_Id, decimal version)
{
    string processKey = string.Format("{0}_v{1}", xml_Id, version.ToString("#0.0"));
    object processLocker = null;
    bool needsExecuting = false;

    lock (_dictionaryLock)
    {
      if (_processes.TryGetValue(processKey, out processLocker) == false)
      {
          needsExecuting = true;
          processLocker = new object();
          _processes.Add(processKey, processLocker);
      }
    }

    lock (processLocker)
    {
        if (needsExecuting)
        {
          // heavy process here which takes about 3 seconds

          _processes.Remove(processKey);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: when you check if it contains the key, and if it does, return from execution: it doesn't wait for the original call to complete, it just returns, right?

Comment: Yes it just returns, but you asked "can i prevent the execution of the function ..."

Comment: Exacly what i wanted. And it is working. I have one more question, which i added it in the question body

Comment: If you used `ConcurrentDictionary`'s `GetOrAdd` with a value factory I think you can do away with the additional dictionary lock @TimRogers?

Comment: This may fail to work properly. Consider the following chart:
http://i.imgur.com/BIqxf8R.png
State 1: Request 1, nothing found in the dictionary, creating "lock 1".
State 2: Request 2, "lock 1" is still in the dictionary, so we reuse it and wait (so far everything is ok).
State 3: Request 1 finished processing, "lock 1" is removed from the dictionary.
State 4: Request 3, "lock 1" is still active, but does not exist in the dictionary. Therefore, requests 2 and 3 will run simultaneously, unlocked. Proposed solution - increment\decrement a counter instead of just adding/removing locks.